# Pulling data from a schedule to designated department sheet

Tags: excel

I created a schedule for my staff in excel. My company has multiple buildings: for example building 1000, 2000, 3000, 5000, 6000, etc.

With 60 employees once I enter the schedule on the master sheet is there any way to have individual building sheets that pull the employee scheduled for that building directly from the master?

Comment: This can be done a few different ways.  Are you familiar with pivot tables?  Can you add an example of what your data looks like?

Comment: hopefully this makes since, I have tried pivot tables but I have employees in rows and each column correlates with the day of the week. some employees work different buildings so when using a pivot table i can only filter through 1 column and if the employee is working in building 2000 mon. & 1000 tues. it removes the employee from the filter. what I am trying to accomplish is if I schedule the employee to work any day in that building there full row would populate in building 1000 sheet.

Comment: Set up your data with one column for employee, one column for building and one column for the date. Then you can pivot that easily.